# At what point should you force a cache in Spark when performing heavy transformations?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark

Say you have something like this:

```
big_table1 = spark.table('db.big_table1').cache()
big_table2 = spark.table('db.big_table2').cache()
big_table2 = spark.table('db.big_table3').cache()
# ... etc
```

And from these tables, you make a number of dfs...

```
output1 = (
 # transformations here: filtering/joining etc the big tables
)

output2 = (
 # transformations here: filtering/joining etc the big tables
)

# ... etc
```

Then you want to combine all the outputs:

```
final_output = (output1
  .union(output2)
  # ...etc
)
```

Then you want to save the results to a table:

```
(final_output
  .write
  .saveAsTable('db.final_output')
)
```

As I understand things, caching is lazy so we need to use an action to force the cache. But at what point in the process above is it best to do that?

Would you do...

```
final_output.count()
```

...just before you write to the table?

In that case, spark would have to go through the whole series of the transformations, then union them, then return the count. So would it go "Ah, you asked me to cache the big_tables - I'll do that first, then I'll use the stuff in memory to help me do all these hairy transformations and create your output."

Or would it go "Ah, you asked me to cache these big_tables. I'll do these big transformations, get the count, and then I'll put all this stuff in memory in case you ask me again."

In other words, would it be better to do...

```
output1.count()
output2.count()
# ... etc
```

...or even...

```
big_table1.count()
big_table2.count()
# ...etc
```

... upstream, to ensure that everything is cached ahead of time?

Or does it not matter where you forced the cache, as long as it happened before you write to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you know what you want to do a `.count` operation on so you can't really choose there. What is important, though, is what you choose to `.cache`.

In general, try avoiding caching very big dataframes/datasets (unless you of course need it). This will fill up Spark storage memory (more info on that [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview)) and leave less space for execution memory.

So in your example, I would look at what you're caching rather than what you are counting.

- If you're only interested in `final_output.count()`, I would cache `final_output` and nothing else.
- If it's the count of `outputX` you're looking for, I would cache those (since you say you're filtering in there and they are not called `big_tableX` I expect them to be smaller
- If you're interesting in the count of the `big_tableX` tables, then you of course need to cache those.

Hope this helps!